# Nicely close windows in xmonad?

Tags: chrome, xmonad

Normally if I close Chrome by clicking on the "X" button on the upper right (in window managers other than `xmonad`, obviously), if I later reopen Chrome then it shows me all my tabs again.

However in `xmonad`, if I close Chrome with `mod+shift+c` and then reopen it my previous tabs are gone and I have to re-open them using the recently closed tabs menu. This indicates to me that Chrome is not getting closed in the same way as when I click on the "X" button.

Since `xmonad` hides said "X" button, how can I close windows in the same way that I would if I clicked on the "X" button?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Ctrl+Shift+Q` to close Chrome instead of `mod+shift+c`. See [Linux keyboard shortcuts for Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/171571)

Comment: This may work for Chrome, but it still would be nice to have something I could use for any window.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution to your question but more of a workaround. I use the Chrome plugin [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en) which among other things, saves the set of tabs currently open so that you can restore them upon restart.